# change video on the fly using javascript and use bootstrap to play on floating window

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

This code is playing video on floating windows using bootstrap. But i want to modify the video src using javascript so i can have dynamic video link. I use onClick() to change the src of the video but it didn't work.

```js
function changevideo() {
  document.getElementById("source").src = "videos/projects/havoc/guide/guide_GOL_101_019_010.mp4";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js">
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <button width="200" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#video" class="img" onClick="changevideo()">click me
        1</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="video">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <video width="100%" autoplay loop>
                        <source id="source" src="">
                    </video>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot to press `play`.

```js
const video = document.getElementById("video-element");

const clear = (node) => {
    while (node.firstChild) {
        node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
    }
};


const changevideo = () => {
  const source = document.createElement('SOURCE');
  
  clear(video);
  
  source.type = "video/mp4";
  source.src = "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4";
  
  video.appendChild(source);
  
  video.play();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js">
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <button width="200" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#video" class="img" onClick="changevideo()">click me
        1</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="video">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <video id="video-element" width="100%" loop>
                    </video>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: there's nothing to play, the video link is broken. I can't see any video.

Comment: @andio the snippet is working for me. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I'm confused. I run the snippet directly here and it's just showing white blank. There's no video. Also tried to copy the code to my editor and same thing. Did you see the video when you run the snippet?

Comment: @andio yes... I'm still viewing the video. Cleared the cache and still working. I'm using Safari. You could have CORS problems. Try adding the 'play' statement to your own code with your own video.

Comment: ok i got it, it's doesn't work on google chrome. i tried on safari and it's working. In google chrome. It's not playing anything and just white blank.

Comment: @andio I did some research and it resulted that Chrome behaves particularly with `video` and `source` elements (see [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/play-returns-promise), the "Danger Zone" enlightened me). I have fixed the code, now it works on Chrome too.

Comment: I works perfectly. Thanks a lot. One question : How to stop it without playback controls? it's set to autoplay, but when i close the video window (simply by clicking on background) , the video is still keep playing. The only way to stop it by showing the contols and press stop.